# Права на создание партиций. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

При попытке создать партицию в определенной схеме получаю ошибку - Must be owner of table.
Команда: create table ... partition of...
Обычные таблицы создаются и удаляются без проблем.
Видимо, недостаточно каких-то прав именно для партиций?

Comment: вопрос то в чем? вам и так ошибка говорит это самое. недостаточно прав для создания партиций именно на этой таблице, где вы не являетесь владельцем/или не входите в группу, или хз как там в постгресе

Comment: Я никак не могу сообразить какие именно права необходимы для создания партиций для пользователя.

Comment: Или пользователь обязательно должен быть участником роли-собственника таблицы? Иначе никак?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> melkij=> create table measurement_y2006m04 partition of **measurement**
> for values from ('2006-04-01') to ('2006-05-01');
>
> ERROR:  must be owner of table **measurement**

Вообще мне сообщение об ошибке кажется вполне очевидно отвечающим, что именно не так.

Совершенно верно, для `create table .. partition of ..` необходимо быть владельцем этой самой партицированной таблицы. Как иначе? `partition of` не только создаёт новую таблицу, но и меняет структуру партицированной головы - её список партиций. Разрешать кому угодно создавать новые партиции - это серьёзная дыра безопасности.

PS: например, есть группа аналитиков. Для них создана отдельная схема, в которой пользователи могут делать свои таблички для сохранения своих результатов. И есть партицированная по дате создания записей табличка, к которой у этих пользователей права только на чтение. Далее, пользователь создаёт новую партицию в своей легитимной схеме. И таким образом через некоторое время получит (как пользователь-владелец партиции) права insert/update/delete в этой партиции. Здорово же?

Comment: Нужно именно partition of, код  - не мой. То есть надо моего юзера включить в группу владельца таблицы... Спасибо.